# AWS API gateway returns 400 error when equal ("=") is in path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

AWS API gateway returns 400 error when equal ("=") is in path

##### Request

```
URL = https://some.cloudfront.net/?key=value=a
```

[image: Request]

##### Result

[image: Result]

The equal ("=") is not supported in AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encode the equals character using standard [URL/percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), representing it as `%3D` instead of `=`.

If you need to decode it before passing it to the underlying Lambda/API, you can use the `$util.urlDecode()` function in the [Integration Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-request.html) of your API.